# i want put this info inside div

Tags: html, css

[image]
so what i miss ?i try to solve it but i cant or should i start again?
that is html code and if you want css too i can send it :

```
    <section id="contact" class="section">
  <!-- Container Starts -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Start Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Start Col -->
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <div class="Container">
          <div class="contactinfo">
              <div>
                <h2>Contact Info</h2>
                <ul class="info">
                  <li>
                    <span><img src="img/contact/Email.png"></span>
                    <span>colbration@visionviewplus.com</span>                        
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <span><img src="img/contact/wechat.png"></span>
                    <span>wechat ID : 212131321</span>                        
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <span><img src="img/contact/qq.png"></span>
                    <span>QQ ID : 212131321</span>                        
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Col -->
     
     
    </div>
    <!-- End Row -->
  </div>
</section>
```

=============================

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? If you want to put a content inside a div, just add content between div tag.

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot showing your problem. Can you also add your CSS so that we may see what styling is being applied?

Comment: it's nothing, According to me, he added fix height to blue box, and other things has padding nd all, so it's overflowing. remove Fixed height it will solve.

Comment: #contact .container .contactinfo {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
width: 550px;
height: 400px;
background: #3c96ff;
z-index: 1;
padding: 15%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#contact .container .contactinfo h2
{
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 50px; }

Comment: #contact .container .contactinfo li
  {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
  }  
#contact .container .contactinfo  span{
 color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 30px;  
  }
#contact .container .contactinfo li span:nth-child(1)
  {
    width: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
  }
#contact .container .contactinfo li span:nth-child(1) img{
  max-width: 200%;
  
}